# Objective-C copy attribute of property not working when using designated inits

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, factory-method

Is this expected behavior?

For instance, with the class declared like so:

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;

+ (instancetype)personWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName birthday:(NSDate *)birthday;

@end

@implementation XYZPerson
+ (instancetype)personWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName birthday:(NSDate *)birthday {
    return [[self alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName lastName:lastName birthday:birthday];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName birthday:(NSDate *)birthday {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _birthday = birthday;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFirstName:@"John" lastName:@"Doe" birthday:[NSDate date]];
}
```

the getter doesn't copy in the following:

```
NSMutableString *name1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"First"];
NSDate *birthday1 = [NSDate dateWithYear:1900 month:10 day:10];

XYZPerson *person = [XYZPerson personWithFirstName:name1 lastName:@"Last" birthday:birthday1];

NSMutableString *n1 = (NSMutableString *)person.firstName;
[n1 appendString:@"ttt"];

NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName);   // Prints Firstttt
```

However, this throws an exception (This is the expected behavior, since the following code calls `appendString` on immutable NSString:

```
XYZPerson *person = [XYZPerson new];
person.firstName = name1;
person.lastName = @"Last";
person.birthday = birthday1;

NSMutableString *n1 = (NSMutableString *)person.firstName;
[n1 appendString:@"ttt"];

NSLog(@"%@", person.firstName);
```

Am I missing something in my code?

**Update**
Additionally, if this is the expected behavior, not an anomaly, should we not use factory methods for properties that should be copied?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString appendString:]` This is the expected behavior

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning to the backing variables. This does not use the accessor methods, and no copying will happen.

And assigning an NSString* to an NSMutableString* doesn't make it mutable. If the compiler doesn't give you a warning for that then change your settings in Xcode.

Comment: I did it intentionally to check its behavior. (Throwing exception is the expected behavior) Also, the official document recommends that users set ivar directly in initializers. This behavior is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I missed to read the following part:

> If you need to set a copy property’s instance variable directly, for example in an initializer method, don’t forget to set a copy of
>   the original object: